# Using Spring Multipart Resolver for specific web page

Tags: spring, multipartform-data

I have two web pages both of them sending multipart-form data. I want to use Spring Multipart Resolver only for one of them and want to treat other separately.

As per my knowledge, with each request Spring checks is it contains multipart-form data(provided xml configuration has multipart resolver entry) and if so it creates MultipartHttpServletRequest object. Basically i don't want to receive this object.

As my entire project is in Spring, there is no way i can go for simple JSP/Servlet config.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by extending the `CommonsMultipartResolver` class and overriding the `isMultipart` method.  If the method returns true the MultipartResolver is applied and a `MultipartHttpServletRequest` is passed to the Spring controller.  If the method returns false a regular `HttpServletRequest` is passed to the Spring Controller.

The `isMultipart` method receives the original `HttpServletRequest` object which you can use to figure out which page will be handling the request and return true or false accordingly.

Once you extend the `CommonsMultipartResolver` use the extended class in place of the `CommonMultipartResolver` in your bean definition.